# How to return data from an async .map() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am looking to return some data from an asynchronous .map() function. It's async due to the `axios` call being inside of it to return some data. I am trying to .map() through an `array []` inside `files.kitchen` and then call axios to get the base64 of each image URL inside `files.kitchen`. I have tried logging the data using await due to the asynchronous behavior of my function. The await returns `undefined` each time. I know I am calling it right by using await. However, I could have a syntax error. I've studied each relative question on here and none of them have worked for me.

Here is my code.

```
  const getbase64Data = () => {
    files.kitchen
      ? files.kitchen.map(async (image, index) => {
          const response = await axios.get(image, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          });
          const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString(
            "base64"
          );
          const data =
            "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + buffer;
          return data;
        })
      : null;
  };
  console.log(await getbase64Data());
```

Please let me know if I need to share anything else.

Comment: There's no `return` in your `getbase64Data()` function.

Answer (score 2):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Arrow functions can have either a "concise body" or the usual "block body".

In a concise body, only an expression is specified, which becomes the implicit return value. In a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

in your code:

```
const getbase64Data = () => {
    files.kitchen
      ? files.kitchen.map(async (image, index) => {
          const response = await axios.get(image, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          });
          const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString(
            "base64"
          );
          const data =
            "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + buffer;
          return data;
        })
      : null;
  };
  console.log(await getbase64Data());
```

getBase64Data has a block body... to use implicit return you need to remove the outer braces...

```
const getbase64Data = () => 
    files.kitchen
      ? files.kitchen.map(async (image, index) => {
          const response = await axios.get(image, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          });
          const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString(
            "base64"
          );
          const data =
            "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + buffer;
          return data;
        })
      : null;
  console.log(getbase64Data());
```

Or, simply add a return statement

```
const getbase64Data = () => {
    var returnArray = files.kitchen
      ? files.kitchen.map(async (image, index) => {
          const response = await axios.get(image, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          });
          const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString(
            "base64"
          );
          const data =
            "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + buffer;
          return data;
        })
      : null;
    return returnArray;
  };
  console.log(getbase64Data());
```

Comment: You were right, along with PLASMA chicken. The implicit return helped me. The return for that was an array of Promises. I then used the `Promise.all()`

Comment: Make sure to mark this Answer as Accepted Answer, so that the Question shows up as Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Robert pointed out in his comment, you need to add a return. If you then get an array full of Promises use Promise.all

I often use something like this:

```js
const fetched = await Promise.all(kitchen.map(async (image, index) => {
            return axios.get(image, {
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
          });
}))
fetched.map(x => { /* do stuff with fetched stuff here */ })
```

Promise.all awaits evey Promise element in the array.

Comment: I was able to use Promise.all just fine, along with DynasticSponge's answer of the implicit return. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const getbase64Data = () => {
  if (files.kitchen) {
    return Promise.all(files.kitchen.map(async (image, index) => { //Promise.all ensures all the async code gets executed
      const response = await axios.get(image, {
         responseType: "arraybuffer",
      });
        const buffer = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary").toString(
          "base64"
        );
        const data =
          "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + buffer;
          return data;
     }));
  }
  return null;
};
console.log(await getbase64Data());
```